# How to copy a table from one db to another using JDBC?

Tags: java, jdbc

We have two Oracle databases which have the same structure. We need to copy the content of one table from one database into another. I'm writing a JAVA program to take care of this task. Since the table's structure may change in the future, the program has to be able to adapt itself.
I tried the following code:

```
try {
                ResultSet rsConfig = getConfigRows(srcDatabase); // this method returns SELECT * FROM TEST_TABLE
                ResultSetMetaData rsmd = rsConfig.getMetaData();
                int colCount = rsmd.getColumnCount();
                String columns = "";
                String values = "";
                for (int j = 1; j <= colCount; j++) {                       
                    columns += rsmd.getColumnName(j);
                    if (j <= colCount)
                        columns += ",";
                    values += "?";
                    if (j <= colCount)
                        values += ",";
                }

                String sql = "INSERT INTO TEST_TABLE(" + columns + ") VALUES("
                        + values + ")";
                PreparedStatement psDest = destDatabase.prepareStatement(sql);

                while (rsConfig.next()) {
                    for (int j = 1; j <= colCount; j++) {
                        psDest.setObject(j, (Object) rsConfig.getObject(rsmd
                                .getColumnName(j)));
                    }
                    psDest.executeUpdate();
                }
```

Is there something wrong with my code ? Any suggestions ?
I should note that for some reason I'm not allowed to use any external tools !

Comment: If you are not allowed to use Oracle Dumps, are you allowed to use ETL tools? Because this would be the next easiest approach.

Comment: Ugly as sin.  You don't close resources, deal with transactions, or use PreparedStatement properly.  I'd use a link or a dump.

Comment: @duffymo I do close my resources ! it is just the top part of the code. This is just a draft code for testing purposes. I'm not going to use this on the actual environment !

Comment: @bmucklow no unfortunately we are not allowed to use any external tools.

Comment: Doesn't explain that abuse of PreparedStatement.

Comment: @bmucklow I'm asking you guys what should I do and I'm telling you what I've already tried.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Don't waste your time. Create a database link and write a few lines in PL/SQL and you are done.

Comment: database link works if we do this on one server. asak it cannot be used when you're dealing with tho different servers.

Comment: No, it doesn't you can do this with arbitrary Oracle databases.

Answer (score 1):

I think you are asking for trouble with this approach.  How often does the table structure really change?  How critical is the data in this table?

I'd suggest you externalize the queries and any other config you find you need, then make sure you have good error handling and gracefully exit if the schema is no longer what you were expecting.

Then you can update configuration and not code if the schema changes.

Comment: to be honest it does not change that much. ideally we wanted the program to be compatible with our future versions but apparently there is no easy way to do it. so probably i'm going to take your advice on this :)